# Rails Bundler on windows refuses to install hpricot (even on manual gem install get Error: no such file to load -- hpricot)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, bundler, hpricot

Upgraded to rails 3, and using Bundler for gems, in a mixed platform development group.  I am on Windows.  When I run Bundle Install it completes succesfully but will not install hpricot.  The hpricot line is:

```
gem "hpricot", "0.8.3", :platform => :mswin
```

also tried

```
gem "hpricot", :platform => :mswin
```

Both complete fine but when I try to do a "bundle show hpricot" I get:

```
Could not find gem 'hpricot' in the current bundle.
```

If I do a run a rails console and try "require 'hpricot'" I get:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- hpricot
```

I have manually installed hpricot as well, and still get the above error.  This worked fine before moving to rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in console and then do bundle install, it will work:

```
gem install hpricot --platform=mswin32
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are using a version of ruby that was built with MinGW in which case your platform will be 'mingw' rather than 'mswin'. Try changing your Gemfile line to the following:

```
gem "hpricot", "0.8.3", :platform => :mingw
```

And if you have other developers that are using the current setup and don't wan to break it for them, change it to this:

```
gem "hpricot", "0.8.3", :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]
```